# How to migrate salesforce outlook configuration to another org using dreamfactory snapshot

Tags: dreamforce

I have to migrate salesforce outlook configuration from one org to another org using snapshot of dreamfactory.
I tried many times on dreamfactory and also spend lot of time to search any solution for this issue on web. But unable to find a single solution.

Please help me to find solution of this issue.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with "snapshot", it is presumably this product https://www.dreamfactory.com/force.com/snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot don't have any option to migrate Outlook configuration. It can be only done by manually.